# Stored procedure using NVL() on input parameter - why?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, nvl

Recently, I have come to analyze a procedure in which they have used below scenario.
I want to know what is the usefulness of this ?

A procedure `(cwrkid, date)`

**select statement**

```
  WHERE CWRK.cwrkid = NVL(in_cwrk_id,CWRK.cwrkid)
```

and `in_cwrk_id` is passed `null`.  SO obviously, `CWRK.cwrkid = CWRK.cwrkid`
will always match... What the point in using variables and passing `null`, and ultimately satisfying a truth condition.

Am I mising something or am I thinking a lot.. :P

Comment: Maybe there are cases, when `in_cwrk_id` is not null. Or this is just a result of the refactoring: someone didn't notice that this piece of code became useless.

Answer (score 0):

This is useful if you want to make the procedure reusable in future development. For now the only usecase is to select all records, but if you ever need to get only one record with a given ID you can also use this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

The point is that the caller can decide whether a filter on `cwrkid` should be applied. One call to that function may pass `NULL` for that parameter, to not apply any filter. Another call to that function may pass some value for that parameter, if that caller does want to apply a filter.

<sub>I say that no filter gets applied, but I am assuming that the column is not nullable. If the column is nullable, then nulls will be filtered out, regardless of what gets passed in as the parameter value.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Normally, code like this is used to have a default behaviour in case the parameter is `NULL`. In this case, the WHERE-condition normally restricts to records with the given `cwrkid`. However, if `cwrkid` is null, there is no restriction.

Without the `NVL`, the WHERE-condition would not match at all.

Why this was done in this case is impossible to know without knowing more about the procedure and its purpose.